# Is it possible to print badges with priceset fields?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I use civicrm 4.6.4 on drupal 7.38.
My event includes dinner with 2 meal types: fish and meat. Along with other options I created a priceset.

I'd like to define event badges (Administer>CiviEvent>Event Badge Layout>New Badge Layout) where the meal type is indicated on. However I didn't find any priceset fields in the list. Only event fees (not using pricesets) are available.  Is it possible to make pricesets fields visible on badges? How do I do that

Many thanks

Johan.

Answer (score 3):

You could use hooks to create custom tokens:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+(and+Custom)+Tokens

Or you can see if the Fancy Tokens extension adds the tokens you need:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens